# Facebook Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, session

I am following the facebooks getting started guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
 but the code given on page not working Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() is not working

package com.example.testapp;

```
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("FB","pass 0");
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Log.d("FB","pass 1");
                      // make request to the /me API
                      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (user != null) {
                                Log.d("FB","pass");
                                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                              }

                        }
                      });

                  }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SessionTracker mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(),
                new StatusCallback() {

                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                    }
                }, null, false);

        String applicationId = Utility
                .getMetadataApplicationId(getBaseContext());
        mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();

        if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
            Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            mCurrentSession = session;
        }
        Log.d("session in login", mCurrentSession + "");
        if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {

            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);

            if (openRequest != null) {
                openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
                openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

                openRequest
                        .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
                Log.e("session closed","session closed");
            }
        } else {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession,
                    new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            Log.e("san<><><>",
                                    user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " "
                                            + user.getInnerJSONObject() + ""
                                            + user.asMap().get("email"));

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Try this